Stop email from sending if it isn't the first Monday of the month
I have a script that sends emails out every Monday. How would I update the below so that the email doesn't send unless it's the first mMonday of the month.
    .CreateReports
    .CreateNewEmail keyName '"Email Subject"
    With .LastEmail
        .AddTo "email.recipient"
    End With
    .SendEmails
    .SetScriptRunSuccess True

I have this below line that sends out an extra email on Sunday, but would like to change it that it prevents emails being sent out unless it's the first Monday of the month:
= (WeekdayName(Weekday(checkDate), True) = "Sun")


You can incorporate the logic from the worksheet formulas in this answer

Hint: the Weekday of a Monday is 2, and the 1st Monday's Day must be between 1 and 7.

First Monday of the month of a date in A1: =A1-DAY(A1)+(7-WEEKDAY(A1-DAY(A1))+2)

First MONDAY will be in 7days obviously, so add condition

check if its monday
check weekday is <=7


@BigBen's comment suggests to check firstly if the Weekday equals 2 (assuming a default argument FirstWeekday:=vbSunday) and as second condition if the actual Day (not: Weekday!) is between 1 and 7; checking the weekday as proposed in your post would result here in a permanent True result as there are only 1..7 results possible.

Would the following work for 2. check weekday is <=7?
= Weekday(checkDate) <= 7
